# Filter Pandas Series by dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series `words` which look like:

```
0             a
1    calculated
2     titration
3         curve
4           for
5        oxalic
6          acid
7            be
8          show
9            at
Name: word, dtype: object
```

I also have a Series `occurances` which looks like:

```
a            278 
show         179
curve         2
Name: index, dtype: object
```

I want to filter `words` using `occurances` in a way that a word would be filtered if it is not in `occurances` or it value is less than 100.

In the given example I would like to get:

```
0             a
8          show
Name: word, dtype: object
```

`isin` only check existence and when I've tried to use apply\map or `[]` operator I got an Error

> Series objects are mutable and cannot be hashed

I can also work with solution on DataFrames.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want the rows that meet the criteria to be filtered in or filtered out? Your expected output is `0             a
8          show` or these rows must be exluded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would need to first filter the specific words you want from your `occurences` Series, and then use the index of it, as the value for the `.isin()`:

```
output = words[words.isin(occurences[occurences > 100].index)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
words[words.apply(lambda x: x not in occurances or (x in occurances and occurances[x]<100))]
```

Answer (score 0):

The isin method works, but generate a list of booleans you should use as index:

```
>> # reproduce the example
>> import pandas as pd
>> words = pd.Series(['a','calculated','titration','curve','for','oxalic','acid','be','show','at'])
>> occurances = pd.Series(['a','show','curve'], index= [278, 179, 2])

>> # apply the filter
>> words[words.isin(occurances[occurances.index > 100])]
0       a
8    show
dtype: object
```